# Calling Intent not working above android version 11 in Java

Tags: android

I am facing an issue in that I cannot send calling Intent  above android version 11 below android version 11 Calling Intent working correctly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
//Demo number
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +"0000000000");
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add below for dial call action,

```
<manifest>
    <queries>
        <!-- Specific intents you query for -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to work in **Android 11 and above**, you have to specify the DIAL intent in `AndroidManifest.xml`. It should be outside `application` tag and inside `manifest` tag.

```
 <queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    </intent>
 </queries>
```

for example :

[image]